# How to get all constraint on table?

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I want to store tables metadata into other table.So how to get all constraint and its type like whether it primary , unique or foreign key in MS SQL server.

```bash
table_name    |   constraint_name   |  constraint_type
--------------|---------------------|-------------------
user          |   pk_user_id        |   PRIMARY_KEY
user_role     |   fk_role           |   FOREIGN_KEY
user          |   unique_email      |   UNIQUE_KEY
```

Comment: Why would you store this information yourself, its already stored and it bring a lot of maintenance with it?

Answer (score 21):

USE [**`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181757.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='tablename'
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Careful! This does not show DEFAULT constraints. `sp_helpconstraint @objname = 'schema.tableName', @nomsg = NULL;` might be more appropriate.